# The audio doesn't play and I can't figure it out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public AudioSource audioscd;
public GameObject nextscn;
    
[SerializeField] Clue firstclue;
[SerializeField] ClueSecond secondclue;
[SerializeField] ClueThird thirdclue;
    
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
  nextscn.SetActive(false);
}
    
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
  if (firstclue.clue1 && secondclue.clue2 && thirdclue.clue3) 
  {
    StartCoroutine (Wait());           
    nextscn.SetActive(true); 
    audioscd.Play();
  }
}
```

So I have three bools (because there are three clues) and when all the three bools are true two things happen:

1. a cube "activates" which is the trigger for the next scene
2. a sound plays

The first thing happens so this works, but the sound doesn't play when I click outside of the "game" screen (still inside unity). The sound plays for a second.

Every clue plays a sound when you find it. Can unity play two sound at once?

What I am not doing right?

Comment: Could you post a complete code? What does `Wait` do? `Can unity play two sound at once?` -> yes if you use multiple audio.source or `PlayOneshot` ... i seem to me you are currently calling `audioscd.Play();` repeatedly every frame => it is always restarting the sound from beginning ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that, when all 3 bools are true, you will call Play() on the AudioSource in every frame. And when calling Play() on an already playing AudioSource it will start from the beginning of the file again. So if there isn't any actual audio content in the very beginning of the file, you won't hear anything - and if there is, you will probably hear some strange glitchy sound.

I will suggest you just add another bool to your script and use that as a filter so you can only do the action related to finding all hints once. For example something like this:

```
public AudioSource audioscd;
public GameObject nextscn;


[SerializeField] Clue firstclue;
[SerializeField] ClueSecond secondclue;
[SerializeField] ClueThird thirdclue;

bool hasFoundAllClues;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    nextscn.SetActive(false);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!hasFoundAllClues && firstclue.clue1 == true && secondclue.clue2 == true && thirdclue.clue3 == true) 
    {
        hasFoundAllClues = true;
        StartCoroutine (Wait());           
        nextscn.SetActive(true); 
        audioscd.Play();
    }
}
```

Another option could be to put the code that is currently in Update() into a coroutine which can be started on Start() and stopped when all 3 clues have been found.

Comment: ... and a small note about the bool comparisons in the if statement: 
`firstclue.clue == true` (and the same with 2nd and 3rd clue, and bool variables in general) can be simplified to just `firstclue.clue` because it in itself is either true or false. 
So in this case we could write the whole if statement as: `if (!hasFoundAllClues && firstclue.clue1 && secondclue.clue2 && thirdclue.clue3)`